# Find the index of the next position containing an empty (not null-defined) string

Tags: java, search, indexing, arraylist

In a larger project, I have created an ArrayList of Strings from a text file, where each line of the text file gets its own index in the ArrayList, so the lines are stored sequentially in the list.

I need the following method to return the next index in the ArrayList that contains an empty line. Since the lines are read in from a file, a line cannot be defined as null when it is read in... or at least I can't get it to work that way either.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
public static int nextBlankIndex(int num){
    //returns the index in the file input arraylist of the next blank line after line number "num"
    //used to find spaces between questions
    for(int i=0; i<in.size();i++)
    {
        String line = in.get(i);
        if(line.equals(""));
            return (num-1)+i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Any advice or edits greatly appreciated, as always. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're adjusting the result by adding `num-1` in the `return` statement. But you're not adding it in all the other places you use `i`, so the search always starts at the first line.

The easiest adjustment is to start the loop at `i = num`.

```
public static int nextBlankIndex(int num) {
    for (int i = num; i < in.size(); i++) {
        String line = in.get(i);
        if (line.equals("")) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

You also had a stray semi-colon after the `if` statement.

Comment: Those damn semicolons... That fixed my issue. Thanks for the correction lol

Comment: Note that you could directly call `line.isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to start from num so start from it and just return the matching index

```
for(int i=num; i<in.size();i++)
{
    String line = in.get(i);
    if(line.equals(""))
        return i;
}
```

Comment: This is effectively what I have tried... unfortunately, I think this specific approach will just return the parameter passed to it, because ANY line will contain "" regardless of whether or not it actually has characters in it. I just copied and pasted this in and ran it and it returned the index that I passed to it consistently.

Comment: sorry I did not spot the bug in the if, just copied your whole code and fixed the indexes. There is no ; after the if bracket.